# SQL - adding new column withouth effecting existing scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

We have a table on the SQL Server 2008 which gets populated by various stored procedures. The problem is that the authors of these stored procedures used some poor choice in code and populated this table using the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO persistant_table
    SELECT * 
    FROM #temp_table_with_data
```

Basically they would create a `#temp_table_with_data` in the script and the columns would be in the same order and with the same name as they are in the `persistant_table`.

Now I need to add another column to this `persistant_table`, but if I do that, I will break all the stored procedures.

Is there a way for me to add a column to this table without breaking all the stored procedures? (In the long run, we will change the stored procedures).

Thank you

Comment: No. Fix the SPs ASAP.

Comment: There is no solution to this. Fix the SPs . It will be better to fix SPs than looking for workarounds that only make matters worse.

Comment: You could create a new persistent table with the new column(s) and the same primary key values as the original table. Then you could create a view which joined the two tables (and provided an appropriate default value for empty rows) and it would be reasonably transparent to users.

Comment: how the #temp_table_with_data is created in your SP? if it's created based on persistant_table during the execution of SP, then the columns on the both table should be equal. so everytime you run the SP, whether if you add new column in the persistant_table, it will also added to #temp_table_with_data when u run the SP, right? Which both tables remain match. Which means that insert statement still work. Or is there something else?

Comment: Give the column name for insert statement and instead of * use only those particular columns which you want to insert.

Answer (score 0):

No I think.select * will pick all columns and column number should match.

I don't think it's big effort to change the line to have particular columns only or select statement to have default value for column or null and then * to store into columns sequentially. But at least 1 line to be changed

Comment: I'm sure there really isn't any good solution to this. I was hoping for something I never knew before.

Comment: if there is same name in columns then i think you can use the sys columns and join but that still need code change.

Answer (score 0):

The "ALTER TABLE" is a SQL statement that allows you to make datatype changes to a database table (i.e. change datatype as well as Size columns from an existing table).

```
 ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName  NVARCHAR(200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it without affecting old scripts. This is why 'SELECT *' is not good practice. You'd better create new scripts with explicit column names like 
SELECT column1, column2 ....